# Select first word in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

maybe this is easy or I overlooked it

but if i have:

```
<div class='test'>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</div>
```

how can i select the first word of it? [in this example 'Fusce']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text of the div, then use a regular expression to parse the text into words:

```
/^(\w+)/.exec($(".test").text())[0]
```

Since the div contents is just textual data (no markup), jQuery can't help you. The example above assumes a "word" is one or more alphanumeric characters, but you could use another regex that suited you better. Other option is to define a set of word boundaries (update: or `\W`, as sgarrett suggested), and split the text to get all words in it:

```
$(".test").text().split(/\ \.\,/)[0]
```

**Update**: and to highlight the word, a slightly modified version of your answer (see the comment about HTML entities):

```
$(".test").html($(".test").html().replace(/^(\w+)/, "<span>$1</span>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.test').text().match(/^(\w+)/)[0];
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v7SZr/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to get the text:

```
var divText = $('div.test').text();
```

Get the first word from the divText:

```
var firstWord = divText.split(/\W+/)[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

so @mgibsonbr should be

```
$div = $('div');

$div.html($div.text().replace(/^(\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nQ5Y5/4/

Comment: Yes, if by "select" you meant to "highlight" it. I assumed you just wanted to retrieve its value...

Comment: BTW, that won't work if you have HTML entities in your div. Try your code with `This is a test string &lt;b>with&lt;/b> the last word` for instance...

Comment: Are you trying to comment on mgibsonbr's answer or answering your question yourself?